# How to make a histogram with MongoDB in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, pymongo, histogram

I want to make a histplot/histogramm which shows the ages of the customers. I use MongoDB with python/pymongo. How can i do this?

I have these objects:

```
{"name": "martin", "age": 20},
{"name": "olaf", "age": 40}
```

Comment: What specifically about this task is giving you trouble? Is it how to approach this task, or a specific part of it?

Comment: I dont know how to get the ages into the histplot. I tried sns.histplot(data=Customers, x=Customers.age) but it doesnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.